# wsdl in iphone and '-id' in value name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wsdl, wsdl2objc

I have little(big) problem:/ I work with WSDL which has input values define in this way: user-id, transfer-id, etc. and after convertion from wsdl to objective-C there are errors because every using of id, xcode recognize as pointer of course. Could I somehow tell xcode that if he meet '-id' to treat as a string(and recognize id as pointer only if there is space before: ' id' or (id) )?

Comment: Can you include an example of the code that is giving you an error?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem: the simplest way was to change (almost) every "-" in project to "_". Now  I have error from server Code=500 "internal server error" and have no idea why:/